# what is the major difference between the given 2 programs having TRY & CATCH and THROWS exception in JAVA

Tags: java

why we need to throws exception when we can handle it by using try and catch...
by using throw...

```
//A void method
public void sample()
{
 //Statements
//if (somethingWrong) then
IOException e = new IOException();
throw e;
//More Statements
}
```

by using try and catch

```
MyClass obj =  new MyClass();
try{
  obj.sample();
} catch(IOException ioe)
{
  //Your error Message here
  System.out.println(ioe);
}
```

they work exactly same. 
what are the major differece between them.. 
plzz explain in POINTS....

Comment: I only see one program here.

Comment: They don't work exactly same. Take a look at a tutorial on Exception Handling in java.

Comment: You don't always know what to do with the Exception, as logging it should be your last resort. In this case you should `throws` it until you know what to do with the exception.